# Checking field values in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

```
if($("#Fees_ProfitType:checked").attr("val") == 29751)
                {
                    FormatAsMoney(this, 10000000000, true); 
                }
                else if($("#Fees_ProfitType:checked").val() == 29751)
                {
                    FormatAsMoney(this, 10000000000, true); 
                }
```

So I have this setup in javascript. When it runs through for Firefox, it notices the first if() as undefined, so it runs to the second, and formats the field.

When I run it through as IE it calls `if($("#Fees_ProfitType:checked").attr("val")`, and returns 29751, however when I compare them, it doesn't equal and won't alert.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might also have to do with the newline before the open parenthesis after your if statement.  There are some cases where Javascript mis-interprets this as not being part of the if statement, and it's generally safer to keep the open paren on the same line as the if.

Comment: I can't seem to find a link off-hand, but it is due to the object literal notation I believe.  This is a Douglas Crockford suggestion.

Comment: I don't have IE on this machine, but can you confirm that the bug is being repeated in this fiddle?  http://jsfiddle.net/idbentley/5stTT/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the value returned be a string.
So, try to do this:

```
$("#Fees_ProfitType:checked").attr("val") == '29751'
```

Or this:

```
parseInt($("#Fees_ProfitType:checked").attr("val"),10) == 29751
```

Cheers

Comment: Could you, please, add this function in your code: Object.prototype.getName = function() { 
   var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
   var results = (funcNameRegex).exec((this).constructor.toString());
   return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
};
This is going to identify the type returned (string, number). To use it, you can do: ($("#Fees_ProfitType:checked").attr("val")).getName()